# Unable to find tokens in string

Tags: php

I am trying to write a small php
application and i am facing a problem.
This is suppose to get text like :

> this is *noun but it is *name.

And
should take the words that start with
a star and add them to the string
tokens. However this is not working.

```
// get list of fields (each should have words delimited by underscores
$storyArray = split(' ', $story);
$tokens = ""; // space-delimited list of fields
for ($i = 0; $i < count($storyArray); $i++) {
    if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*')
        $tokens .= $storyArray[$i] + " ";
}
$tokensArray = split(' ', $tokens);
```

Comment: If you want performance and are not using regex, then explode() may give you some increased speed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"+" is for addition, not string concatenation. It casts its arguments as numbers, which will always be 0 in your source.

On another note, splitting `$tokens` is unnecessary. Instead, append tokens to `$tokensArray`:

```
$story = "this is *noun but it is *name";
// get list of fields (each should have words delimited by underscores
$storyArray = split(' ', $story);
$tokens = ""; // space-delimited list of fields
$tokensArray=array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($storyArray); $i++) {
    if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*') {  
        $tokens .= $storyArray[$i] . " ";
        $tokensArray[] = $storyArray[$i];
    }
}
```

If you only needed `$tokens` for generating `$tokensArray`, you can get rid of it. Also, depending on whether you need `$storyArray`, `preg_match_all(...)` might be able to replace your code:

```
preg_match_all('/\*\w+/', $story, $tokensArray);
$tokensArray = $tokensArray[0];
```

Comment: i am trying to print a table on the screen with text boxes for people to fill in the info from that (NOT WORKING:():
echo "<form action=\"story.php\" method=\"post\">
  <input name=\"fields\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$tokens\" />
  <input name=\"story\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$story\" />
  <table>";
for ($i = 0; $i < count($tokenArray); $i++) {
 $fieldWords = split('_',$tokensArray[$i]);
 echo "<tr><td>";
 echo $fieldWords[0];
 for ($j = 1; $j < count($fieldWords); $j++) {
  echo " ".$fieldWords[$j];
 }
 echo ":";
 echo "</td><td><input name=\"$tokensArray[$i]\" type=\"text\" /></td></tr>";
}

Comment: i will post it in a different questiton :)

Answer (score 9):

Wow, I can't believe I've been debugging this and missing the obvious fault!

This line here:

```
$tokens .= $storyArray[$i] + " ";
```

You must concatenate with a period (`.`), not a plus sign! What you have right now is basically the same as `$tokens .= 0;`

Comment: Just had the same *D'uh!* experience. :o)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me:

```
$story = "this is *noun but it is *name";

$storyArray = split(' ', $story);
$tokens = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($storyArray); $i++) {
  if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*') {
    array_push($tokens, substr($storyArray[$i], 1));
  }
}
var_dump($tokens);
$tokenString = implode(" ", $tokens);
```

Note that I'm pushing the tokens directly into an array, then imploding it.

Comment: +1 Put them in an array directly if what you need is an array anyway. I'd suggest `$tokens[] = $story...`, but that's just me.

Comment: can i make it instead of an array just a string that is separated by spaces and without the star, so it would like : "noun_1 noun_1 adjective" etc ?

Comment: You could implode the array like $string_of_tokens = implode(" ", $tokens)

Comment: You bet... Just use the `substr` and `implode` functions. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: so what i have now is this :
$storyArray = split(' ', $story);
$newTokens = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($storyArray); $i++) {
  if ($storyArray[$i][0] == '*') {
    array_push($newTokens, $storyArray[$i]);
  }
}
$tokens = implode(" ", $newTokens);

but it is not working :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a regular expression to achieve the same effect, without all the string manipulation you are doing right now. This would be the most elegant solution:

```
$string = "this is *noun but it is *name";

// Lets set up an empty array
$tokens = array();

preg_match_all('/\*\w+/m', $string, $tokens);
$tokens = $tokens[0]; // Only one sub-pattern, dropping unnecessary dimension.

var_dump($tokens);
```

Regular expressions exists to do mainly exactly the kind of task you are trying to achieve now. They are usually faster than doing string manipulations manually (Regular Expression engine in PHP is compiled code).

To explain my regex:

- **`/`:** start boundary
- **`\*`:** an asterisk (`*`)
- **`\w`:** any alpha-numeric character or underscore
- **`+`:** previous marker, 1 or more times. (match `\w` one or more times)
- **`/`:** end boundary
- **`m`:** multiline modifier

Comment: Also you can use the regexpr pattern `\b` for *word boundary* instead of spaces.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately, `*` is considered to be a *word boundary*, so it will not work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
$tokens .= $storyArray[$i] + " ";
```

with

```
$tokens .= $storyArray[$i]." ";
```

And

```
$tokensArray = split(' ', $tokens);
```

with

```
$tokensArray = split(' ', rtrim($tokens));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tokens .= $storyArray[$i] + " ";
```

in this line, you should be using the . operator to concatenate strings.